# virtual network manage multiple ip

Tags: ubuntu, networking, firewall, ip, vps

I have an Private Virutal Server with two ip.

Th OS is Ubuntu 16.

I would like to allow only* the ports 22,80,442 on the first ip and Allow the ports 12301,12302,12303,12304 on the second ip.

How I can do this ?

is there an command or a file to configure it ?

Comment: It sounds like you want to set and configure a [firewall](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/serverguide/firewall.html)

Comment: note that ssh(22) and apache(88,443) allow an explicit `Listen 192.168.12.34:22` which will make you unable to connect on port 22 to 192.168.12.X (X≠34).